# Unable to locate package libc6:i386

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, multiarch

I'm new to this OS, and I wanted to get steam... I looked up the commands online, and tried to perform them.  I didn't find a problem until a little ways in.  I looked everywhere for an answer and tried all the stuff.  Ultimately I cannot find the answer to this anywhere:

So I want to install the package `libc6:i386`.
I have already done the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

after these lines, I try:

```
$ sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

So at this point, I should have the 32-bit architecture as a foreign architecture on my machine, and I should have it updated.

But when I attempt to get the packages I need, such as `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`, `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`, `libc6:i386`, I get a response like:

```
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package** 'the package I am trying to install...'
```

I haven't found any information on a problem like this online, so if there is any help you can give me, that would be awesome.

edit:

The output for `apt-cache policy libc6 libc6:i386` can be found below

`libc6:
Installed: 2.23-5
Candidate: 2.23-5
Bersion table: *** 2.23-5 100 100/var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Unable to locate package libc6:i386`

`dpkg --print-architecture` prints

`amd64`

Yes, I am sure I did `apt-get update` after I called `dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Though there is no output when I call `dpkg --add-architecture i386`, and the only output for update is for steam.  For this reason, I believe there is a problem adding the architecture, but there is no information given.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy libc6 libc6:i386`?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg --print-architecture`? Are you certain that you ran `apt-get update` after `dpkg --add-architecture i386` and that both ran without errors or warnings? It doesn't hurt to run them again if you're unsure.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe could be explained by the fact that the architecture is hard-coded in the mirror list at `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Even after you run dpkg --add-architecture, if the mirrors you are using list explicitely `[arch=amd64]`, then apt will not find the i386 package even after running `apt update`:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
```